# Google Pub/Sub message ordering not working (or increasing latency to over 10 seconds)?

Tags: go, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm trying to make a simplified example demonstrating the use of Google Pub/Sub's message ordering feature (https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/ordering). From those docs, after message ordering is enabled for a subscription,

> After the message ordering property is set, the Pub/Sub service delivers messages with the same ordering key in the order that the Pub/Sub service receives the messages. For example, if a publisher sends two messages with the same ordering key, the Pub/Sub service delivers the oldest message first.

I've used this to write the following example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "time"

    "cloud.google.com/go/pubsub"
    uuid "github.com/satori/go.uuid"
)

func main() {
    client, err := pubsub.NewClient(context.Background(), "my-project")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("NewClient: %v", err)
    }

    topicID := "test-topic-" + uuid.NewV4().String()
    topic, err := client.CreateTopic(context.Background(), topicID)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("CreateTopic: %v", err)
    }
    defer topic.Delete(context.Background())

    subID := "test-subscription-" + uuid.NewV4().String()
    sub, err := client.CreateSubscription(context.Background(), subID, pubsub.SubscriptionConfig{
        Topic:                 topic,
        EnableMessageOrdering: true,
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("CreateSubscription: %v", err)
    }
    defer sub.Delete(context.Background())

    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    defer cancel()

    messageReceived := make(chan struct{})
    go sub.Receive(ctx, func(ctx context.Context, msg *pubsub.Message) {
        log.Printf("Received message with ordering key %s: %s", msg.OrderingKey, msg.Data)
        msg.Ack()
        messageReceived <- struct{}{}
    })

    topic.Publish(context.Background(), &pubsub.Message{Data: []byte("Dang1!"), OrderingKey: "foobar"})
    topic.Publish(context.Background(), &pubsub.Message{Data: []byte("Dang2!"), OrderingKey: "foobar"})

    for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
        select {
        case <-messageReceived:
        case <-time.After(10 * time.Second):
            log.Fatal("Expected to receive a message, but timed out after 10 seconds.")
        }
    }
}
```

First, I tried the program without specifying `OrderingKey: "foobar"` in the `topic.Publish()` calls. This resulted in the following output:

```
> go run main.go
2020/08/10 21:40:34 Received message with ordering key : Dang2!
2020/08/10 21:40:34 Received message with ordering key : Dang1!
```

In other words, messages are not received in the same order as they were published in, which in my use case is undesirable and I'd like to prevent by specifying an `OrderingKey`

However, as soon as I added the `OrderingKey`s in the publish calls, the program times out after 10 seconds of waiting to receive Pub/Sub messages:

```
> go run main.go
2020/08/10 21:44:36 Expected to receive a message, but timed out after 10 seconds.
exit status 1
```

What I would expect is to now first receive the message `Dang1!` followed by `Dang2!`, but instead I'm not receiving any messages. Any idea why this is not happening?

Comment: have you tried, checking the `sub.Receive` function to see if there is any error.

Comment: You should also check the result of `topic.Publish` [method](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/pubsub?tab=doc#Topic.Publish).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The publishes are failing with the following error: `Failed to publish: Topic.EnableMessageOrdering=false, but an OrderingKey was set in Message. Please remove the OrderingKey or turn on Topic.EnableMessageOrdering`.

You can see this if you change your publish calls to check the error:

```
res1 := topic.Publish(context.Background(), &pubsub.Message{Data: []byte("Dang1!"), OrderingKey: "foobar"})
res2 := topic.Publish(context.Background(), &pubsub.Message{Data: []byte("Dang2!"), OrderingKey: "foobar"})

_, err = res1.Get(ctx)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Failed to publish: %v", err)
    return
}

_, err = res2.Get(ctx)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Failed to publish: %v", err)
    return
}
```

To fix it, add a line to enable message ordering on your topic. Your topic  creation would be as follows:

```
topic, err := client.CreateTopic(context.Background(), topicID)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("CreateTopic: %v", err)
}
topic.EnableMessageOrdering = true
defer topic.Delete(context.Background())
```

Answer (score 0):

I independently came up with the same solution as Kamal, just wanted to share the full revised implementation:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "flag"
    "log"
    "time"

    "cloud.google.com/go/pubsub"
    uuid "github.com/satori/go.uuid"
)

var enableMessageOrdering bool

func main() {
    flag.BoolVar(&enableMessageOrdering, "enableMessageOrdering", false, "Enable and use Pub/Sub message ordering")
    flag.Parse()

    client, err := pubsub.NewClient(context.Background(), "fleetsmith-dev")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("NewClient: %v", err)
    }

    topicID := "test-topic-" + uuid.NewV4().String()
    topic, err := client.CreateTopic(context.Background(), topicID)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("CreateTopic: %v", err)
    }
    topic.EnableMessageOrdering = enableMessageOrdering
    defer topic.Delete(context.Background())

    subID := "test-subscription-" + uuid.NewV4().String()
    sub, err := client.CreateSubscription(context.Background(), subID, pubsub.SubscriptionConfig{
        Topic:                 topic,
        EnableMessageOrdering: enableMessageOrdering,
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("CreateSubscription: %v", err)
    }
    defer sub.Delete(context.Background())

    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    defer cancel()

    messageReceived := make(chan struct{})
    go sub.Receive(ctx, func(ctx context.Context, msg *pubsub.Message) {
        log.Printf("Received message with ordering key %s: %s", msg.OrderingKey, msg.Data)
        msg.Ack()
        messageReceived <- struct{}{}
    })

    msg1, msg2 := &pubsub.Message{Data: []byte("Dang1!")}, &pubsub.Message{Data: []byte("Dang2!")}
    if enableMessageOrdering {
        msg1.OrderingKey, msg2.OrderingKey = "foobar", "foobar"
    }
    publishMessage(topic, msg1)
    publishMessage(topic, msg2)

    for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
        select {
        case <-messageReceived:
        case <-time.After(10 * time.Second):
            log.Fatal("Expected to receive a message, but timed out after 10 seconds.")
        }
    }
}

func publishMessage(topic *pubsub.Topic, msg *pubsub.Message) {
    publishResult := topic.Publish(context.Background(), msg)
    messageID, err := publishResult.Get(context.Background())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Get: %v", err)
    }
    log.Printf("Published message with ID %s", messageID)
}
```

When called with the `enableMessageOrdering` flag set to `true`, I receive `Dang1!` first, followed by `Dang2!`:

```
> go run main.go --enableMessageOrdering
2020/08/11 05:38:07 Published message with ID 1420685949616723
2020/08/11 05:38:08 Published message with ID 1420726763302425
2020/08/11 05:38:09 Received message with ordering key foobar: Dang1!
2020/08/11 05:38:11 Received message with ordering key foobar: Dang2!
```

whereas without it, I receive them in reverse order as before:

```
> go run main.go
2020/08/11 05:38:47 Published message with ID 1420687395091051
2020/08/11 05:38:47 Published message with ID 1420693737065665
2020/08/11 05:38:48 Received message with ordering key : Dang2!
2020/08/11 05:38:48 Received message with ordering key : Dang1!
```